# Toggle comes on but not off

Tags: javascript, toggle

I recently tried to do toggle on and off for a div, however using many methods, I was not able to do it due to the the link going to .com/#

until I found a post which make it happen without the redirect to #

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggleVisibility(newSection) {
        $("#info").not("#" + newSection).hide();
        $("#" + newSection).show();
    }
</script>
```

I am still learning JavaScript and I do not know how to add in toggle off.
now it just toggles on and when i press it it does not toggle off.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle does both show and hide, based on the element's current display visibility. So something like this should work:

```
function toggleVisibility(newSection) {
    $("#" + newSection).toggle();
}
```

Comment: YOU ARE A LIVE SAVER. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you may want tabs: when one panel is selected the other panels disappear.

here's one common way to do it:

```
$('a.tab').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.panel:visible').hide();
    var el = $($(this).attr('href'));
    el.toggle();
});
```

you have links that show a particular panel in a group and hide the others:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .panel {display: none;}
</style>

<a class="tab" href="#panel1">Show/hide panel 1</a>
<a class="tab" href="#panel2">Show/hide panel 2</a>
<a class="tab" href="#panel3">Show/hide panel 3</a>

<div class="panel" id="panel1">1</div>
<div class="panel" id="panel2">2</div>
<div class="panel" id="panel3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What the code you have given does is hide all elements with an ID of `info` that do not have the ID given in `newSection`, then shows the `newSection` one.

Since elements can only have one ID, it's kind of weird and pointless to treat the elements as if they might have more than one, or if there might be more than one of the same.

You could just use the `.toggle()` method: `$("#"+newSection).toggle()`

Comment: YOU ARE A LIVE SAVER TOO THANK YOU!